# Xamarin.Forms + ReactiveUI MasterPage OnItemListener

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

How do you listen to the MasterPage.OnItemSelected within the code behind of a MasterPage and within the `this.WhenActivated(disposables => {});` function?  Or should I somehow do this in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Observable.FromEventPattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229251(v=vs.103).aspx).
Assuming you're using a ListView in your MasterPage:

```
this.WhenActivated (d => {
    Observable.FromEventPattern (h => MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += h, 
                                 h => MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected -= h)
              .Subscribe (DoSomethingWithMySelectedItem)
              .DisposeWith (d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with Qonstukt's help I ended up doing:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs>(h => masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += h,
                                                h => masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected -= h)
                            .Subscribe(x => OnItemSelected(x.Sender, x.EventArgs))
                            .DisposeWith(disposables);
```

...

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem is MasterPageItem item)
        {
            var nextPage = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            nextPage.BarBackgroundColor = Constants.ToolbarColor;
            nextPage.BarTextColor = Constants.ToolbarTextColor;
            Detail = nextPage;
            masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```